# Want to learn Microsoft-Dynamics CRM. Please suggest for Dynamics Beginners?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I need to work on a Dynamics project in next 3 months with Pharmaceutical client. I have been working on .NET technologies from last couple of years. Now I am interestred in learning Microsoft Dynamics.

Please suggest how and where to start for the Dynamics Beginners...... your ideas/ any tutorial links / materials/ Books/ Traning/ And your experience?

Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the stuff from Sonoma Partners to be helpful when I worked with CRM.  Their book [Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625948) was very helpful.  Their blog is ok but not very developer focused - http://blog.sonomapartners.com/.

Other useful stuff I found:

- Ronald Lemmon writes a good CRM blog here : http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/
- http://crm.georged.id.au/ - this is a great blog for code samples and real world problem solving

Hope this stuff helps.

Comment: Agreed, the book from Sonoma Partners help a lot for beginners to intermediate developers.

Answer (score 3):

I got the CRM4 book: Working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  Good and thick introductory book.

Answer (score 1):

I have both the Working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and both are excellent. I'd suggest getting both. The Working with title really helps understanding of how MS CRM works, the programing title helps with more advanced development tasks.  Both are from Sonoma partners.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using "Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0" (Microsoft Press) and "CRM as a Rapid Development Platform" by David Yack.

The Programming book has been really good for helping me to come to grips with the SDK.

David yack's book has been a really good intro to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Both working with CRM and Programming with CRM are good books however, make sure you check your CRM version before buying these books as few new things (dynamic list being one of the most important one) have been added in 2011 version.

The book I like the most is step by step. It's much more practicle for me (others might differ) also get 30 day free trial of dynamic CRM from here to practice --> [CRM.DYNAMICS.COM](http://crm.dynamics.com/en-gb/home?WT.mc_id=UK_SB_SF_DYN_CMO_Search)

I am in the same boat as you. Just started a job with CRM and have to learn it all in few weeks. Another good sourse is --> [PluralSight/CRM](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=dynamics-crm&highlight=julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m03-marketing%2a2!julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m04-reporting!julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m06-customize!julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m01-intro%2a2,4!julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m05-processes!julie-yack_dynamics-crm-m02-managing#dynamics-crm-m03-marketing). Again free trial, although they are so good I ended up with paid account.